# Java stored procedure running slow

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a java web application that uses the next function to execute a stored procedure, it connects to SQL Server 2008:

```
Class.forName(sDriver_Reportes);
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(sDB_URL, sUSER, sPASS);
sQuery = "{call procGetResult(?)}";
proc = conn.prepareCall(sQuery);
proc.setString("pDate", sDate);
proc.execute();
rs = proc.getResultSet();
```

but it takes about 7 minutes to return the resultset, if I execute the sp it takes just 10 seconds to show the result.

I were looking for some similar case but only found post about parameter sniffing and connection pool but anyone seems to be like mi case because the sp is running fast, could you give me some info about where else to look about this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The sp it's working fine, it just take 10 secs to execute in SQL Server, the problem it's when it runs in code, it takes 7 mins to complete.

Comment: There is an error in your code, please correct it.

Comment: If you talk about the missing ", it was a typo.

Comment: setString can be used with this 2 forms: public void setString(int parameterIndex, String x) throws SQLException or public void setString(String parameterName, String x) throws SQLException, this is the reference https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html   public static void getSupplierOfCoffee

Comment: The question mark it's the placeholder for the parameter.

Comment: Only the execute line takes a long time? Put some time info around it. Getting the connection is fast? Other SQL on that connection run from java are fast?

Comment: I smell parameter sniffing. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem of  SQL Server Parameter Sniffing. The first thing you need to check is the execution plan for your stored procedure.You can view it using the following icon in SQL Server Management Studio:

[image: Click on the icon marked in Red]

Now being exposed to the problem here are a few methods to address it:

1. Create SQL Server Stored Procedures using the WITH RECOMPILE Option
2. Use the SQL Server Hint OPTION (RECOMPILE) Use the SQL Server Hint
3. OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR) Use Dummy Variables on SQL Server Stored
4. Procedures Disable SQL Server Parameter Sniffing at the Instance
5. Level Disable Parameter Sniffing for a Specific SQL Server Query

For implementation and better understanding you can refer the below link :
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3257/different-approaches-to-correct-sql-server-parameter-sniffing/

Comment: Hi guys, thank you all for you help, indeed it was parameter sniffing, I modifiy the sp to use dummy variables and it's working perfectly, Thank you.

Comment: @JCM You can express your thanks by upvoting me...This was my first answer on Stack Overflow...Just Kidding...You can share your exact solution as it might help others

Comment: I up voted your answer, I don't know why it's not showing it.